# Dynamic programming - Tree recursion with Memoization

Tags: go, recursion, dynamic-programming, memoization

For the problem:

> Consider an insect in an M by N grid. The insect starts at the bottom left corner, (0, 0), and wants to end up at the top right corner, (M-1, N-1). The insect is only capable of moving right or up. Write a function paths that takes a grid length and width and returns the number of different paths the insect can take from the start to the goal.

[image]

> For example, the 2 by 2 grid has a total of two ways for the insect to move from the start to the goal. For the 3 by 3 grid, the insect has 6 diferent paths (only 3 are shown above).

---

Below is the recursive solution:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func paths(m, n int) int {

    var traverse func(int, int) int
    traverse = func(x, y int) int {

        if x >= m || y >= n {
            return 0
        }
        if x == m-1 && y == n-1 {
            return 1
        }
        return traverse(x+1, y) + traverse(x, y+1)
    }
    return traverse(0, 0)
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(paths(1, 157))
}
```

---

As N increases, below is the effect:

```
fmt.Println(paths(1, 1)) // 1
fmt.Println(paths(2, 2)) // 2
fmt.Println(paths(3, 3)) // 6
fmt.Println(paths(4, 4)) // 20
fmt.Println(paths(5, 5)) // 70
fmt.Println(paths(6, 6)) // 252
fmt.Println(paths(7, 7)) // 924
```

---

Memoization can be applied in fibonacci problem, to reuse previous computations, using tree recursion

Does it make sense to memoiz this path problem? to reuse previous computations

(Note: this problem is meant to apply the idea of tree recursion, as mentioned [here](https://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/%7Ecs61a/sp20/lab/lab04).)

Comment: What is the effect as N increases?

Comment: @user2864740 Edited query with the answer for your question. But that does not decide, whether memoization can be used. Because there is no overlap/repetition on computations, because we need to find difeerent paths.

Comment: The problem is well known, and has a solution of (M+N-2 choose M-1) or equivalently (M+N-2 choose N-1). Does it make sense to use memoization which would take O(NM) time? Not really, since binomial coeffecients can be computed in O(min(M,N)) time with relatively simple code (for example `big.NewInt(0).Binomial(M+N-2, M-1)`)

Comment: @PaulHankin Why the problem statement is saying `paths(3,3)` is 3 but not 6? I see 6 paths.

Comment: There are only 3 paths (of the possible 6) shown in your diagram. That's all it's saying.

Comment: @PaulHankin Sorry my English is bad, Is the `paths(3,3)` expected output  `6` or `3`?

Comment: It's 6 as you correctly state in your question.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is well known, and has a solution of (M+N-2 choose M-1) or equivalently (M+N-2 choose N-1). Does it make sense to use memoization which would take O(NM) time? Not really, since binomial coeffecients can be computed in O(min(M,N)) time (arithmetic operations) with relatively simple code.

For example ([playground link](https://play.golang.org/p/BVw4teY_5Rn)):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/big"
)

func paths(n, m int) *big.Int {
    return big.NewInt(0).Binomial(int64(n+m-2), int64(m-1))
}

func main() {
    for i := 1; i < 10; i++ {
        fmt.Println(i, paths(i, i))
    }
}
```

Comment: This problem is meant to apply the idea of tree recursion, as mentioend [here](https://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~cs61a/sp20/lab/lab04/)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible to use memoization. A key observation to make is consider a grid (1, 1) in a 3x3 grid:

(2, 0) (2, 1) (2, 2)

(1, 0) (1, 1) (1, 2)

(0, 0) (0, 1) (0, 2)

The number of paths in grid (1, 1) is equal to the number of paths from (1, 0) plus the number of paths from (0, 1) since there are only two possible ways one can arrive at path (1, 1).

Generalizing:

**npath(x, y) = npath(x-1, y) + npath(x, y-1)**

where npath(x, y) = the number of possible paths to visit grid (x, y)

Thus, if you build your recursion backwards you can apply memoization. By backwards I mean you have to start from the smaller case where npath(_, 0) = 1 and npath(0, _) = 1. **underscore** means any value.

A simple run of this algorithm leads to these number of paths in a 3x3 grid:

1 3 6

1 2 3

1 1 1

In fact, you can just do a double nested loop instead of a recursion as an optimization.

Comment: why should I start from `(x,y)`. What is the advantage? In the above code, I started from `(0,0)`

Comment: for me it's just easier to think that way, but you can do the other way as well.

Comment: See my generalization in the comment. The idea in dynamic programming is usually to start with a smaller case. So think about smaller case first (i.e. grid 1x1, 1x2, 2x1, 2x2). Then figure out how to compute bigger case given a smaller case.

Comment: That is how you apply memoization naturally, once you have answer (memoize) for a smaller case, you can compute the larger case.